# Seleccionar el último producto de cada categoría

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola tengo tablas categorías y productos donde cada producto, pertenece a una categoría cada producto esta relacionado con su categoria mediante el campo category_id, listo los productos por categoria con:

```
 $categories = Product::orderBy('category_id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Pregunta: como puedo hacer que la base me entregue solo un producto por categoria?

Necesito listar las categorías mostrando un producto por cada una de ellas

---

**Edicion**

hola modifiqué  solo un poco la solución que me diste pero me  entrega solo las categorías

Lo que quiero conseguir es que de cada categoría muestre el último de los productos que se cree para poder tener siempre actualizada la portada de un catálogo.

```
$products = Category::with(['products' => function($query){
            $query->where('id','(SELECT MAX(id)');
        }])->get();
```

Ya que veía que podía pedir el ultimo también pidiendo el máximo id

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**edición**

```
$products = Category::addSelect([
                      "ultimo_anadido" => function($query) {
                             $query->select("name")
                             ->from("products")
                             ->whereColumn("category_id", "categories.id")
                             ->take(1)
                             ->latest();
                       }
               ])->get();
```

Me da este error:

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Y ¿que características debe tener el único producto a devolver?

Comment: hola que sea el ultimo de la lista. Gracias

Comment: Tu tabla productos tiene alguna columna que guarde la fecha de registro?

Comment: hola si  $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 0):

- Vamos a trabajarlo a través de una sub consulta
- Usamos el método **`addSelect`** en el cual indicamos:

  - Nombre de la columna nueva generada
  - El valor a través de una función que esa columna tendrá
- Seleccionamos de la tabla relacionada que sería por ejemplo el nombre del producto
- Indicamos en el **`from`** el nombre de la tabla relacionada
- Por medio del método **`whereColumn`** indicamos que se busque la igualdad de la llave primaria de la table **`categories`** Con la llave foránea de la tabla **`products`**
- Limitamos a 1 el retorno de registros
- Para obtener el registro de producto más reciente con **`latest()`** ordenamos de forma descendente por la columna **`created_at`**

Consulta

```
Category::addSelect(["ultimo_anadido" => function($query) {
    $query->select("name")
          ->from("products")
          ->whereColumn("category_id", "categories.id")
          ->limit(1)
          ->latest();
}])->get();
```

Comment: gracias por contestar , lo pruebo y te digo!!!

Comment: ok muchas gracias mañana lo debo probar en la mañana, te aviso

Comment: hola que tal probé la solución pero no puedo imprimir los productos, imprime las Categorias, cada una por el último de sus productos, pero no puedo imprimir ese producto.

Comment: hola!!!  voy a actualizar el post para mostrar lo que hice

Comment: Ok Gracias, Lo que quiero conseguir es que de cada categoría muestre el último de los productos que se cree para poder tener siempre actualizada la portada de un catálogo.

Comment: Excelente, espero!

Comment: hola me da un error. edité el post

Comment: hola buen día, si, le había corregido la sintaxis, pero me da el mismo ese error

Comment: hola uso laravel 5.6, puedes pegar tu ejercicio para verlo de todas maneras me va a servir. Gracias por todo

Comment: Ok gracias, lo voy a tener como una posibilidad, aunque tengo el proyecto ya funcionando sin esa funcionalidad, tu ayuda igual me podría  servir en otros trabajos. Gracias